# Iterate Visio shapes using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I have a number of Visio process flow diagrams which I need to:
1) extract the text from the shape
2) categorize the shapes based on the shape type (e.g. Process or System/Database)

Does anyone know or have any good sample code that I can study from?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not clean but worked out for me.

First open the document with something like:

```
import win32com.client
visio_application = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Visio.Application")
try:
    opened_doc = app_visio.Documents.Open(visio_file)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error" + str(e))
```

This is the way I added all pages from an opened document to a list.

```
pageCounter = int(opened_doc.Pages.Count)
listOfVisioPages = []
for i in range(1, pageCounter + 1, 1):
    print("Pagenumber: " + str(i))
    pageI = self.opened_doc.Pages.Item(i)
    print("Pagename: " + str(pageI.Name))
    listOfVisioPages.append(pageI)
```

Now you only need to parse every page for the shape information.

```
listofShapes = []
shapes = page.Shapes
shapeCounter = shapes.Count
for j in range(1, shapeCounter + 1, 1):
   listofShapes.append(shapes.Item(j))
```

For getting the shapetext use

```
shape_text = shape.Text
```